# %s variable in Query Execution Python 3.8 (pymssql)

Tags: python, variables, pymssql

I have a python script with a basic GUI that logs into a DB and executes a query.

The Python script also asks for 1 parameter called "collection Name" which is taken from the tkinter .get function and is added as a %s inside the Query text. The result is that each time I can execute a query with a different "Collection name". This works and it is fine

Now, I want to add a larger string of Collection Names into my .get function so I can do cursor.execute a query with multiple collection names to get more complex data. But I am having issues with inputing multiple "collection names" into my app.

Below is a piece of my Query1, which has the %s variable that it then gets from the input to tkinter.

```
From #Session1
    Join vGSMRxLevRxQual On(#Session1.SessionId = vGSMRxLevRxQual.SessionId)
Where vGSMRxLevRxQual.RxLevSub<0 and vGSMRxLevRxQual.RxLevSub>-190 
    and #Session1.CollectionName in (%s)
Group by
    #Session1.Operator
Order by #Session1.Operator ASC

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SelectedSession1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #SelectedSession1 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Session1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Session1
```

1. Here, is where I try to execute the query

   ```
   if Query == "GSMUERxLevelSub" :
   result = cursor.execute(GSMUERxLevelSub, (CollectionName,))
   output = cursor.fetchmany

   df = DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())

   filename = "2021_H1  WEEK  CDF GRAPHS().xlsx"

   df1 = DataFrame.transpose(df, copy=False)
   ```
2. Lastly, here is where I get the value for the Collection name:

CollectionName = f_CollectionName.get()

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7j4D.png)
enter code here

Comment: For example , In MS SQL Studio, i can execute a query with multiple "Collection Names" by doing the folowing:

#query stuff......
.......
and #Session1.CollectionName in ('CollectionName1','CollectionName2','CollectionName3')
..............

Now, How do I do this with python?? How do I make my (%s) be like 

'CollectionName1','CollectionName2','CollectionName3' -- format

Answer (score 0):

Your issues are due to a list/collection being a invalid parameter.

<s>You'll need to transform collectionName</s>

```
collection_name: list[str] = ['collection1', 'collection2']
new_collection_name = ','.join(f'"{c}"' for c in collection_name)

cursor.execute(sql, (new_collection_name,))
```

Not sure if this approach will be susceptible to SQL injection if that's a concern.

Edit:
Forgot the DBAPI would put another set of quotes around the parameters. If you can do something like:

```py
CollectionName = ["foo", "bar"]
sql = f"""
From #Session1
    Join vGSMRxLevRxQual On(#Session1.SessionId = vGSMRxLevRxQual.SessionId)
Where vGSMRxLevRxQual.RxLevSub<0 and vGSMRxLevRxQual.RxLevSub>-190 
    and #Session1.CollectionName in ({",".join(["%s"] * len(CollectionName))})
"""

sql += """
Group by
    #Session1.Operator
Order by #Session1.Operator ASC
"""

cursor.execute(sql, (CollectionName,))
```

EDIT: Update to F-string

Comment: Ill test and get back to you, Your explaination is understood. Thanks a million and Ill let you know what happens soon.

Comment: My issue so far is that CollectionName is inputed from Keyboard into a text box and taken by the code as CollectionName = textbox.get()

If it is 1 collection name typed into the text box then the query executes fine. If I add a string of many collection Names it does not work. So i need to make the .get function know how to separate each collection name that I entered as a long string somehow....

Comment: iF i input "A" (without the "") in the text box , then the query will work because it takes "A" and puts it into the (%s) and makes it look like ("A") [Which is the format I need]
For multiple inputs I would need (%s) to look like this --> ("A","B","C") 
The problem is that the inputs will be valiable, sometimes 1 input, sometimes 2 or 3 etc...

Comment: Updated the response